# Javascript: Identify when a new, second element appears and use function only on the older one (mutation observer)

Tags: javascript, dom, mutation-observers

I know there are lots of answered questions about the mutation observer on here. But I couldn't find a solution yet.

On a website, I have a result window that opens when I click on something with a specific tool. When I click on another object with that tool, a new result window will open but the old one won't close.
**So I want that the old window closes when the new one appears**.
I can do that manually because they have a closing button. So I can use a simple click function to close it:

```
document.querySelector('[title="closeButton"]').click();
```

The problem is, I just want to close the old window, when a new one appears. I tried to use a mutation observer to see when a result window appears, but even that didn't work. Although I already used such an observer in another place without problems.

```
function closeResultWindow() {
  let observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
    let found = mutations.find(mutation => Array.from(mutation.addedNodes)
      .find(node => node.id ?
        node.id.includes("lefttabs_tablist_module_") : false))
    if (found) {
      console.log("Resultwindow found")
      document.querySelector('[title="closeButton"]').click();
      }
  });
  
  observer.observe(document.body, { 
    childList: true, subtree: true 
    });
};
```

I tried it with different functions with the observer. But this one is a function I already used successfully with another problem and just adjusted it to this one. The `lefttabs_tablist_module_` is the widgetid of the result window. Every window has another number behind the `lefttabs_tablist_module_`.

For example window1 has `widgetid=lefttabs_tablist_module_1256` and the next window2 has `widgetid=lefttabs_tablist_module_7549`. It doesn't seem to be chronological.

**The observer above was just a test to see if I can identify at least one result window. But the goal is to observe when a new window is opened, so there are two, and use the click function to close the older one.**

Does anyone have an idea how that would be possible?
Or at least what the problem is in my code to identify one window with the observer.

Comment: In your code `lefttab` has an `s`, in your text they don't. But in your text the attribute is `widgetid`, while your code is looking for `id`.

Comment: I don't think you need mutation-observers for this case, Could you reproduce the issue on a stackoverflow snippet, or any live editor like codesandbox, so we can debug and help you.

Comment: @Kaiido Oh yeah sorry, it was a typo. I changed it.
And you're right with the id thanks. But node.widgetid isn't possible. And one level below the element with widgetid, it has the same with id. So I don't think it will matter.

Comment: If you need to check the `widgetid` attribute then it's `node.getAttribute("widgetid")`

Comment: @Mina I will try. But I'm not sure how to reproduce it in a snipped. It's quite complex.

Comment: @Kaiido thanks but it still raises an error. Can I just replace `node.id` with `node.getAttribute("widgetid")` in both cases?
Like that: 

`.find(node => node.getAttribute("widgetid") ?
        node.getAttribute("widgetid").includes("lefttabs_tablist_module_") : false))`

Comment: Yes that should work

Comment: @Kaiido mhm it doesn't. It says:

`Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'observe' on 'MutationObserver': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.`

Comment: That's because you're not calling  `observer.observe(document.body)` anymore, but something else. (Can't see it, so can't help you)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok guys I solved it. It now works like that:

```
function closeResultWindow() {
  let observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
    let found = document.querySelectorAll('[widgetid^="lefttabs_tablist_module_"]');

    if (found.length >= 2) {
      console.log("Resultwindow found")

      // find old result window
      let closeButton = found[0].querySelector('[title="Close"]');

      // close result window
      if (closeButton) { 
        closeButton.click();
        console.log("old result window closed");
      }
    }
  });
    observer.observe(document.body, { childList: true, subtree: true });
}

closeResultWindow();
```

Now it instantly closes the old window when I open a new one.
Thanks for your help and answers!

Comment: valid method. instead of observe `document.body` probably only to the targeted node/element instead.